# Maximizing vibration data sampling rate from ADXL357 for condition monitoring application

Tags: conditional-statements, monitoring, esp32, vibration, arduino-esp32

`I am building a vibration monitoring application using ADXL357 with esp32 microcontroller. As per the information provided in cbm setup guide by ADI the number of datapoints collected in a second should be 5khz for 2.4 khz bandwidth.

I have set the ODR_LPF at 2000 Hz and 500 Hz and HPF_CORNER at 6.2084 × 10−4 × ODR. and esp32 baud rate at 115200 through I2C.

Problem:

I am getting 350 - 410 samples of vibration data in a second when I run a count to calculate the no of samples/sec.

Question

How can I get 5000 data samples/ sec ?

Is my way of measuring the sampling data rate using a counter correct?

Kindly provide me some guidance in the right direction.

Thanks.

```
enter code here
#include "Seeed_adxl357b.h"

#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR)
    #pragma message("Defined architecture for ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR.")
    #define SERIAL Serial
#elif defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAM)
    #pragma message("Defined architecture for ARDUINO_ARCH_SAM.")
    #define SERIAL SerialUSB
#elif defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD)
    #pragma message("Defined architecture for ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD.")
    #define SERIAL SerialUSB
#elif defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_STM32F4)
    #pragma message("Defined architecture for ARDUINO_ARCH_STM32F4.")
    #define SERIAL SerialUSB
#else
    #pragma message("Not found any architecture.")
    #define SERIAL Serial
#endif


#define CALI_BUF_LEN           15
#define CALI_INTERVAL_TIME     250
int32_t cali_buf[3][CALI_BUF_LEN];
int32_t cali_data[3];

float factory;

Adxl357b  adxl357b;

int count;

int32_t deal_cali_buf(int32_t* buf) 
{
    int32_t cali_val = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < CALI_BUF_LEN; i++) 
    {
        cali_val += buf[i];
    }
    cali_val = cali_val / CALI_BUF_LEN;
    return (int32_t)cali_val;
}


void calibration(void) 
{
    int32_t x;
   // SERIAL.println("Please Place the module horizontally!");
    delay(1000);
   // SERIAL.println("Start calibration........");

    for (int i = 0; i < CALI_BUF_LEN; i++) {
        if (adxl357b.checkDataReady()) 
        {
            if (adxl357b.readXYZAxisResultData(cali_buf[0][i], cali_buf[1][i], cali_buf[2][i])) {
            }
        }
        delay(CALI_INTERVAL_TIME);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        cali_data[i] =  deal_cali_buf(cali_buf[i]);
        // SERIAL.println(cali_data[i]);
    }
    x = (((cali_data[2] - cali_data[0]) + (cali_data[2] - cali_data[1])) / 2);
   
//    SERIAL.print("Cali data 0: ");
//    SERIAL.println(cali_data[0]);
//    SERIAL.print("Cali data 1: ");
//    SERIAL.println(cali_data[1]);
//    SERIAL.print("Cali data 2: ");
//    SERIAL.println(cali_data[2]);
//    SERIAL.print("x value avg: ");
//    SERIAL.println(x);
      factory = 1.0 / (float)x;
//    SERIAL.print("factory: ");
//    Serial.println(factory);
    
   }

void setup(void) {
    uint8_t value = 0;
    float t;

    SERIAL.begin(1000000);
    if (adxl357b.begin()) {
        SERIAL.println("Can't detect ADXL357B device .");
        while (1);
    }
   // SERIAL.println("Init OK!");
    /*Set full scale range to ±40g*/
    adxl357b.setAdxlRange(TEN_G);
    /*Switch standby mode to measurement mode.*/
    adxl357b.setPowerCtr(0);
    delay(100);
    /*Read Uncalibration temperature.*/
   // adxl357b.readTemperature(t);

//    SERIAL.print("Uncalibration temp = ");
//    SERIAL.println(t);
   calibration();

}


void loop(void) {
    int32_t x, y, z;
    uint8_t entry = 0;
    if (adxl357b.checkDataReady()) 
    {
        adxl357b.getFifoEntry(entry);
//        SERIAL.print("FIFO entry = ");
//        SERIAL.println(entry);
        if (adxl357b.readXYZAxisResultDataFromFIFO(x, y, z)) 
        {
            SERIAL.println("Get data failed!");
        }

//        float  x = x*factory;
//        float  y = y*factory;
//        float  z = z*factory;


      //  SERIAL.print("");
         Serial.println(count);
       // SERIAL.print((x* factory));
        
        Serial.print(x);
          SERIAL.print(',');
       // SERIAL.print("Y axis = ");
       // SERIAL.print((y* factory));
        SERIAL.print(y);
      // SERIAL.print(y*float(0.00));
        SERIAL.print(',');
       // SERIAL.print("Z axis = ");
      //  SERIAL.println((z* factory));
     
        SERIAL.println(z);
       // SERIAL.println('');
       count = count+1;
    }
   // delay(10);
    
}
```

Comment: ADXL357 supports standard rate (100KHz), fast (1MHz) and high speed (3.4MHz) I2C communication. Your constraint is because of your 115200bps Serial print, assuming each sampling take 24 bytes + 2 bytes overhead, so it  is 26 bytes or 260 bits(with start, parity, and stop bit), 115200/260 = 443 samples, which is about right from what you getting.

Comment: At 1000000 baud rate, high speed I2C communication, still ~ 410 samples/sec receiving. samples doesn't increases on changing baud rate.

Comment: If you can't debug yourself and need help, show your code... We can only guess.

Comment: @hcheung Thanks for mentioning,  I have uploaded the code kindly let me know if any solution comes out.

Comment: You said that you set "high speed I2C communication", how did you do that? as far as I can tell form the [library](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Seeed_ADXL357B/blob/ce8f280a8abdb7ecc6864769485ed53545951a03/Seeed_adxl357b.cpp#L41) you are using, it run at standard rate (i.e. 100kbps). The library doesn't call [wire.setClock()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/wire/setclock/) to set higher data rate.

Comment: I have already set the clock in .cpp file (local) to 3.4MHz. but thanks to you, I forgot to set it at ADXL357 end so I set It the bit high for highspeed mode, now I am getting 1450 samples/sec. It is still less than the desired sample rate. Its my first time hands on with this so facing problems.